# Room migration: "no such table: room_table_modification_log"

Tags: android, sqlite, database-migration, android-room

Room 1.1.0 version.

I am getting this error on the first run after migration.

It runs well if I close the app and start it again.

```
ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:1182)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:792)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:518)

Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM proposals WHERE hotel_id = ?)
#################################################################
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1095)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:660)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
    at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:64)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.compileStatement(RoomDatabase.java:244)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.createNewStatement(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:65)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.getStmt(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:77)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.acquire(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:87)
    at com.hotellook.db.dao.FavoritesDao_Impl.removeProposals(FavoritesDao_Impl.java:723)
```

The DB initialization code looks like this (Dagger AppModule)

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDataBase(app: Application): AppDatabase =
  Room.databaseBuilder(app, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
      .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
      .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
      .build()

private companion object {
  const val DATABASE_NAME = "app.db"

  val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN column0 TEXT;")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN column0 TEXT;")
    }
  }

  val MIGRATION_2_3 = object : Migration(2, 3) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
      database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table0 (column1 INTEGER NOT NULL, column2 TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(column1))")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN column1 TEXT;")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN column2 TEXT;")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN column3 REAL;")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN column1 TEXT;")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN column2 REAL;")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table3 ADD COLUMN column1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;")
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table3 ADD COLUMN column2 TEXT;")
    }
  }
```

The app upgrades from version 2 to 3.
How can I fix it?

Comment: please add `MIGRATION_1_2` and `MIGRATION_2_3`

Comment: done. only MIGRATION_2_3 matters as application is updating from version 2 to 3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bump up the version to 1.1.1-rc1 and this nonsensical error that stems from Google's own code will not happen anymore, I've tested the same scenario on numerous devices.

Also see my [question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420649/upgrading-room-db-with-migrations-causes-db-lock)

Comment: Bumping to 1.1.1-rc1 will probably solve this. Here is the [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79362399) about this issue.

Comment: What about Room 2.x?

Comment: if it builds upon 1.1.1-rc1 and later, then obviously it will work

Comment: If it branched before 1.1.1 and they didn't port the fix to the 2.0 branch, then it wouldn't. Since we don't have the source, we can't see the commit that fixed the issue, and we don't have (AFAIK) had any feedback (even acknowledgement) from Google on this, then we can't tell. I have had this issue with 2.0.0-alpha for some time now, so my guess is that your "obviously" is not _that_ obvious.

Comment: My bad, Yigit _did_ mention they'd do an AndroidX release to fix that bug, but that comment is 3 months old. But _obviously_ using 2.x is no guarantee that it has the fix, quite the opposite actually.

Comment: Well, they just released 2.0 RC1. I guess it's fixed then.

Comment: I am facing this problem even with version 2.1.0-alpha07.

Comment: try moving to 2.1.0-beta01 :D, released not too long ago

Comment: I am facing same crash in 2.2.5

Comment: revert back to older version then, where it doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this crash.
my private key type and foreign key type is not equal ,

after set equal type,  crash not happen

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i failed with this bug when I used LiveData and overrided onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) when i created instance of RoomDatabse

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            .addCallback(object : Callback() {
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
                    initTypeDataFirstTime(context)
                }

                override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onOpen(db)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        db.disableWriteAheadLogging()
                    }
                }
            })
                .build()
```