# Room Database : Multiple delete query crashes app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to delete a row from my database based on Room in my android app. When user delete a row from the database, the operation is successful. But, when the user deletes another row, the app crashes. 
If the user deletes a row and then restarts the app to delete another row, the delete operation works fine.

Here's the log:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database '/data/user/0/com.basusingh.blingoo/databases/wordLayList' is not open.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.throwIfNotOpenLocked(SQLiteDatabase.java:2943)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.createSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:564)
        at android.database.sqlite.-$$Lambda$RBWjWVyGrOTsQrLCYzJ_G8Uk25Q.get(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:558)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.getSession(SQLiteProgram.java:123)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:46)
        at com.basusingh.blingoo.Database.WordLayList.WordLayListDao_Impl.DeleteWordLayList(WordLayListDao_Impl.java:94)
        at com.basusingh.blingoo.Activity.WordLayListViewer$1doTask.doInBackground(WordLayListViewer.java:156)
        at com.basusingh.blingoo.Activity.WordLayListViewer$1doTask.doInBackground(WordLayListViewer.java:148)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
E/ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM room_table_modification_log WHERE invalidated = 1;
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1229)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:703)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1840)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:328)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:311)
        at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.checkUpdatedTable(InvalidationTracker.java:415)
        at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(InvalidationTracker.java:389)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here's the DAO code:

```
@Dao
public interface WordLayListDao {

    @Query("DELETE FROM WordLayListItems WHERE uid = :id")
    void DeleteWordLayList(int id);

}
```

And other class,

```
public class WordLayListDatabaseClient {

    private Context mCtx;
    private static WordLayListDatabaseClient mInstance;

    private WordLayListAppDatabase appDatabase;


    private WordLayListDatabaseClient(Context mCtx) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;



        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mCtx, WordLayListAppDatabase.class, "wordLayList").build();
    }

    public static synchronized WordLayListDatabaseClient getInstance(Context mCtx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new WordLayListDatabaseClient(mCtx);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public WordLayListAppDatabase getAppDatabase() {
        return appDatabase;
    }
}
```

```
@Database(entities = {WordLayListItems.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class WordLayListAppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract WordLayListDao wordLayListDao();
}
```

This is how I'm calling the database:

```
 private void deleteLayList(){
        class doTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... aa){
                WordLayListDatabaseClient.getInstance(WordLayListViewer.this).getAppDatabase().wordLayListDao().DeleteWordLayList(o.getID());
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String var){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WordLay List Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }

        doTask dt = new doTask();
        dt.execute();
    }
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that your path name is `/data/user/0/com.basusingh,blingoo/databases/wordLayList`, with a ',' in your package name. Could that be a reason?

Comment: No, that was a mistake. Typo. I've corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: What version of Room are you on? Bumping the version might work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370683/room-migration-no-such-table-room-table-modification-log/50420698

Comment: I'm currently on 2.2.1

Comment: `no such table: room_table_modification_log`. I think you forget to add your newly created table to the entities

Comment: @nfl-x what's that supposed to mean? I have no table named "room_table_modification_log".

Comment: Try creating a smaller example with the room entity in question. And when you can recreate the issue, share the code with us.

Comment: @BasuSingh when the user tries to delete another row, is the previous async task in progress or was it already finished?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir, the previous async task is finished. User cancels the activity. When he goes back to the activity and delete it, the app crashes. However, when user cancels the activity and close the app and then open it again and delete, it happens successfully.

Comment: class inside method does it make sense??

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi it does the job

Comment: remove class code from method and only use last 2 line in that method.

Comment: Which version of room do you use? Did you try bump room version?

Comment: @MarekKondracki I'm using 2.2.1. What's a bump room version?

Comment: @BasuSingh Bumping the version means updating the version of the library. You can now update to the latest version 2.2.2 . Release note: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_222_3

Comment: what is WordLayListItem class? Share this class to check, these codes are fine and must work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Room - Database gets locked after a delete query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970801/room-database-gets-locked-after-a-delete-query)

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing Integer Id try passing object.!

> or

Create a Async task for deleting data in background.
[Tutorial](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-6-working-with-architecture-components/lesson-14-room,-livedata,-viewmodel/14-1-b-room-delete-data/14-1-b-room-delete-data.html)

hope this may helps you.

```
 @Delete
 void delete(WordLayListItem wordLayListItem);
```

Comment: Tried passing object. Still the error. All task is done inside Async task.

Answer (score 0):

First, what I noticed you're facing might be a deadlock.
Secondly I notice a table called ***room_table_modification_log*** might not have been created and yet trying to be accessed!
Finally, note that the issue is not from your Dao.
So, If you created a migration that maybe failed, you will get this kind of error, so you might want to remind you self how to create migrations in Room...like below.

> Your Migration:

```
private static final Migration ADDED_CARD_TABLE = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `CardEntity` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "`type` TEXT, " + "`lastFour` TEXT)");
    }
};

//and Below to add it to your db builder and don't forget to update the version later.
        sampleDB = Room.databaseBuilder(context, sampleDB.class, "sample_db") .addMigrations(ADDED_CARD_TABLE).build();
```

> And finally you should use do database manipulation in the background like using async below:

```
class DeleteItemInDb extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        //Here goes your deleting process.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Setup precondition to execute some task after deleting ?
    }
}
```

Doing your database operations in the background helps you avoid longer operations slowing down your app response because it's basically running on the main thread!
and also I don't know how many threads you're using to access your db but you also need to know how to access your db using multiple threads, you can post your code here on how you're access and updating your db if all the above solutions did not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Share the link to your full project on Github.

All the pieces of code you pasted above worked perfectly fine without any crash even when I deleted from the database several times

Comment: Can you share some light on what exact package and version I should use. I tried replacing my version number of room to 1.1.1-rc1 and gradle failed because it couldn't find the file.

Comment: There is a piece of information you are not sharing with us that is causing the crash. I copied and pasted all the pieces of code you have and modified it to work with a todolist app on my studio. There was absolutely no crash even after I deleted several items from the taskDetail activity and using room 2.1.1.

Comment: I used all the codes you posted in the question to build an app and everything worked fine with no issues and no crashes whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I think some where in your application your are closing database instance by using

```
 db.close();
```

find the above line and comment it out, and check with the same scenario. Check and let me know if it fixes this issue.

Comment: I'm not. There's no such line in my code. Probably a bug?

Answer (score 0):

you have to  close the database connection after delete. Reload the database connection and update your list view.

Comment: Can you share some code that can help with closing the database based on my current code.