# Room - Database gets locked after a delete query

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to delete a row from my database. When I first delete it for the first time, the row gets removed successfully. After I try to remove another row, I get an error that the db is not open/ is locked. I have posted the logcat and the code.

Also, if I delete a row for the first time, it gets delete and when I close the app and open it back again and delete another row, it works.  Only if I continue to delete another row without closing the app, I get the error.

Here's the log:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database '/data/user/0/com.basusingh.blingoo/databases/wordLayList' is not open.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.throwIfNotOpenLocked(SQLiteDatabase.java:2943)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.createSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:564)
        at android.database.sqlite.-$$Lambda$RBWjWVyGrOTsQrLCYzJ_G8Uk25Q.get(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:558)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.getSession(SQLiteProgram.java:123)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:46)
        at com.basusingh.blingoo.Database.WordLayList.WordLayListDao_Impl.DeleteWordLayList(WordLayListDao_Impl.java:94)
        at com.basusingh.blingoo.Activity.WordLayListViewer$1doTask.doInBackground(WordLayListViewer.java:156)
        at com.basusingh.blingoo.Activity.WordLayListViewer$1doTask.doInBackground(WordLayListViewer.java:148)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
E/ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM room_table_modification_log WHERE invalidated = 1;
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1229)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:703)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1840)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:328)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:311)
        at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.checkUpdatedTable(InvalidationTracker.java:415)
        at androidx.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(InvalidationTracker.java:389)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here's the DAO code:

```
@Dao
public interface WordLayListDao {

    @Query("DELETE FROM WordLayListItems WHERE uid = :id")
    void DeleteWordLayList(int id);

}
```

And other class,

```
public class WordLayListDatabaseClient {

    private Context mCtx;
    private static WordLayListDatabaseClient mInstance;

    private WordLayListAppDatabase appDatabase;


    private WordLayListDatabaseClient(Context mCtx) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;



        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mCtx, WordLayListAppDatabase.class, "wordLayList").build();
    }

    public static synchronized WordLayListDatabaseClient getInstance(Context mCtx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new WordLayListDatabaseClient(mCtx);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public WordLayListAppDatabase getAppDatabase() {
        return appDatabase;
    }
}
```

```
@Database(entities = {WordLayListItems.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class WordLayListAppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract WordLayListDao wordLayListDao();
}
```

This is how I'm calling the database:

```
 private void deleteLayList(){
        class doTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... aa){
                WordLayListDatabaseClient.getInstance(WordLayListViewer.this).getAppDatabase().wordLayListDao().DeleteWordLayList(o.getID());
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String var){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WordLay List Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }

        doTask dt = new doTask();
        dt.execute();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the database after deleting the first time? Does it delete successfully, looking at logcat it means you tried to delete your database when it was closed. Most likely you had an error first after deleting the first time

Comment: Yes, I have checked. It deleted successfully. I fetch the updated list from the database.

Comment: Have you tried deleting but not using AsyncTask?

Comment: No not yet. I will try it today. Any other ideas?

Comment: No, Usually I would delete the object using the Room's built-in Query. It's @Delete

Comment: Delete the data here I think it is unnecessary to use AsyncTask and display a dialog box. I see "setResult (RESULT_OK); finish (); "it seems that you are finishing an activity after it is completed, why should you do that?

Comment: setResult is for the calling activity.

Comment: @Chanh, using "@Delete" can we remove all the rows in the table, similar to DELETE from Table  query ?  If yes, how to do that ?

Comment: use 'DELETE FROM myTable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue this way.

Instead of using the singleton class to insert or delete, I'm simply calling this code directly:

```
 WordLayListAppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                        WordLayListAppDatabase.class, "wordLayList").build();
                db.wordLayListDao().DeleteWordLayListByObject(o);
```

Now, I'm using the singleton class to only fetch the data. To update the database, I'm using the code above (The above is always called in Async Task).

Comment: How could this work ? Are you using two different instances of db for this ? Does LiveData work properly for u ?